Use Dapr bindings.localstorage inside k8s
I running a dapr component inside k8s with the following yaml file, I need to create a directory inside the cluster.
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: ifms-filestore-pv
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi 
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/filestore

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ifms-filestore-pvc
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi  


---

apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: ifms-dapr-filestore
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  type: bindings.localstorage
  version: v1
  metadata:
    - name: rootPath
      value: "/tmp/filestore"
    - name: connection
      value: "ifms-filestore-pvc"


i get the following error
{"app_id":"vehicle-management","instance":"vehicle-management-859dc79596-b8p8g","level":"fatal","msg":"Fatal error from runtime: process component ifms-dapr-filestore error: [INIT_COMPONENT_FAILURE]: initialization error occurred for ifms-dapr-filestore (bindings.localstorage/v1): [INIT_COMPONENT_FAILURE]: initialization error occurred for ifms-dapr-filestore (bindings.localstorage/v1): unable to create directory specified by 'rootPath' /tmp/filestore: mkdir /tmp/filestore: read-only file system","scope":"dapr.runtime","time":"2024-04-29T09:20:07.622723479Z","type":"log","ver":"1.13.2"}


Did you solve it? I was having the same problem, and after breaking my head on the wall, I changed to Azurite for local environments and Azure on AKS.
